# docker-compose can not retrieve variables from SOME.env files

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

As stated in https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#envfile, I can put environments variables into specific files. But I can not make it. Could not figure it out in the past hours, even I have upgrade both docker(Docker version 1.12.5) and docker-compose(version 1.9.0) to the lateste versions.

- docker-compose.yml:

  ```
  version: '2'
  services: 
    box:
      image: busybox
      env_file: tt.env
      command: echo $RACK_ENV
  ```
- tt.env

  ```
  # Set Rails/Rack environment
  RACK_ENV=development
  ```

The output of ***docker-compose up*** will be like this:

```
WARNING: The RACK_ENV variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
Creating test_box_1
Attaching to test_box_1
box_1  |
test_box_1 exited with code 0
```

This means the variable set in the tt.env file are not retrieved successfully. please let me know where I was wrong.

Comment: ".env" works, but I need the features to assign this file name to switch environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Compose reads `.env` file by default for variable substitution, so that's why it is working. 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

> You can use a $$ (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a
>   literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a
>   value, so a $$ allows you to refer to environment variables that you
>   don’t want processed by Compose.

So you have to change your compose file a little bit:

```
version: '2'
  services:
    box:
      image: busybox
      env_file: tt.env
      command: ["sh", "-c", "echo $$RACK_ENV"]
```

Comment: wow, this made the difference. Thanks a lot, Lauri! Now I totally understand the doc :)